# Get gallery in loop through ajax

Tags: loop, images, ajax, gallery

So, calling this PHP from click through **ajax** I manage to display Title and content in my **modal**.
But when the code gets to `get_post_gallery` it always returns **null**.

```
$the_query  = new WP_Query(array('p' => $pid));

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $data = '
        <div class="post-container">
            <div id="project-content">
                <h1 class="entry-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h1>
                <div class="entry-content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>

            </div>
        </div>  
        ';

        if ( get_post_gallery( ) ) :
                $gallery = get_post_gallery(get_the_ID(), false );              
        endif;
    }
}
```

On a side note, the method works on a **single.php** page. So I assume it's a problem of context. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will return an array try to print r the $gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing $pid instead of using `get_the_ID()`?

```
if (get_post_gallery($pid)) :
   $gallery = get_post_gallery($pid, false);
endif;
```

Comment: yup, I tried that too.